# Using Angular 2 to return HTML from C#/.NET service

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have an existing .NET application that I want to update to use an Angular 2 front-end. There is a section of a page that has dynamic content and every time I want to get the most up-to-date content, I currently use jquery similar to this:

```
$.get("/Plan/Variety/VarietyList")
            .done(function (data) {
                PlaceReturnedData($("body"), data, "variety-list-selling");
            });
```

The data returned is the exact HTML I need, no need to manipulate it.

How can I use Angular 2 to return this same data? I've looked around and only see how to handle JSON data, such as the example below from Angular 2's Tour of Heroes tutorial:

**heroes.component.ts:**

```
heroes: Hero[];
selectedHero: Hero;

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private heroService: HeroService
) { }

getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('initializing MenuVarietiesComponent');
    this.getHeroes();
}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

**heroes.component.html:**

```
<ul class="heroes">
    <!-- On click, execute onSelect() function and pass in the hero variable from the ngFor. Apply the "selected" class if hero & selectedHero match, remove it if they don't -->
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
        (click)="onSelect(hero)" 
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span>
        <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
        <!-- We need to stop propagation so we don't trigger the onSelect() method on the <li> -->
        <button class="delete" (click)="delete(hero); $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>  
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I modify the example Angular 2 code above to handle HTML data rather than JSON data so I can take advantage of code I already have set up on the C# end? I'm guessing the `*ngFor` in the html is irrelevant since I probably won't need to save my data as an array and I would probably need to change the value of `heroesUrl` to `/Plan/Variety/VarietyList`, but I'm a little stuck after that.

EDIT:
Here is what the returned HTML from my controller might look like:

```
    <div class="varietyTypeName" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="">
        Greens
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-toggle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in collapsableArea">
        <div class="varietyFamilyName">Arugula</div>            
        <div class="varietyName">
            <a class="ajax-rep rep-main-col" href="/Plan/Selling/DetailsPPVS/5409">Astro</a>
            <a href="#deleteVarietySelling" id="deleteVarietySelling_5409" class="quick-delete fa-minus-button" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in collapsableArea">
        <div class="varietyFamilyName">Kale</div>                 
        <div class="varietyName">
            <a class="ajax-rep rep-main-col" href="/Plan/Selling/DetailsPPVS/3720">Kalettes</a>
            <a href="#deleteVarietySelling" id="deleteVarietySelling_3720" class="quick-delete fa-minus-button" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How does html look like?

Comment: Which HTML? My .NET controller returns the exact HTML that I need (no need to format it with Angular) and it should be placed inside of <menu-varieties></menu-varieties>. Does that answer your question?

Comment: you say - controller returns exact HTML. what HTML that is what I'm asking.... show me that HTML code...

Comment: I edited my post to include that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizationService} from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class SideBarComponent implements OnInit {
    myHTML;

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizationService, private myService : MyHTTPService){

        myService.getHTMLFromBackend().subscribe(
            data => {
                    this.myHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data.content)
            });
        }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Then when you are trying to use it in the html (DOM) Just simply do

```
{{myHTML}}
```

Comment: Does this code assume I have a file with a class called MyHTTPService? What do I put in that file?

Comment: Yes you need to create a service file like:

`import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyHTTPService{

constructor() {}

getHTMLFromBackend(){
//Perform http call here and simply return it
}
`

Comment: I may be missing something, but it looks like you have an extra closing brace. Was subscribe( supposed to be subscribe{, or was that closing brace before ngOnInit(){} supposed to be a ) ?

Comment: I'm also not sure how to return the html. I've been modifying examples I've found and can't get it to work.

Comment: I've edited the main post to match the changes, I was indeed missing a )